# Can level quik be poured over wood subfloor

Tags: wood, subfloor

HOME Depot will install Laminate in all the floor of my house. My first floor is concrete, my second floor is wood, they use level quik to level my second floor. My question is that if they can use it? In the future is it possible that it will crack and I will hear noise in the first floor when somebody walk in the second floor? Or some water is possible to go into the wood subfloor? Thank you very much and appreciated your advises.

Answer (score 2):

The self leveling compounds work quite well on both wood and cement floors.
My house is a daylight basement and the upper Kitchen floor was in rough shape. The only problem I had was a hole I forgot to patch.
Some of the compound did make its way to the lower level and I did have to add some to a little over 18 inch square to make it flat.
That vinyl has been there since 2008 and I have had no problems.
Even with all the small cracks the only area I had anything come through was the hole that was 1/2" wide by about 3" long it had some sawdust in it and I forgot about it untill the wife asked me about the stuff dripping in my Man Cave.